# What is a datetime-type column in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I'm having to do some work where I am interacting with and creating tables that are manipulated by the [SQLite.net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) library. I need to be able to create tables that the other program won't know it didn't create itself.

While looking at some schemas and getting a feel for how it creates things, I noticed something odd. When I read about [SQLite's data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), I see that it's a small list, and initially it looked to me like if I want to store a date/time I need to make sure I use special functions in SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE queries, and the column can be TEXT or INTEGER or REAL. If I forget a datetime() function somewhere, I expect to get something back that isn't what I wanted (except for maybe a TEXT column.)

So I'm looking at the schema for one of the tables, and I see this in the columns:

```
"LastUpdated" datetime ,
```

Uhh, OK. 'datetime' isn't a type. Or is it? The 'type affinity' rules indicate that 'datetime' is a valid type specifier and will be considered NUMERIC. OK, nothing really off there. I try a query:

```
sqlite> select datetime(LastUpdated) from Foo;
2016-01-06 15:37:36
```

That makes sense. I bet if I forget the datetime() function I get something goofy back, right?

```
sqlite> select datetime(LastUpdated) from DestinationAdapter;
2016-01-06 15:37:36
```

Uhhh... OK. That'd make sense if it's a TEXT column, I guess. So I made a test table:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE TestDateTime ( 
   ...>   "Id" integer primary key autoincrement not null,
   ...>   "Value" TEXT,
   ...>   "ValueN" NUMERIC);
sqlite> INSERT INTO TestDateTime(Value, ValueN) VALUES (datetime('2015-01-06 10:20:30'), datetime('2015-01-06 10:20:30'));
sqlite> select * from TestDateTime;
1|2015-01-06 10:20:30|2015-01-06 10:20:30
```

OK. This is getting weird. It seems like SQLite is storing something that isn't the value discussed in the data type document. Whatever it is, it tells SQLite's console tool that the value in the column is a date/time value, and should be presented as such. So what exactly is going on? It seems like no matter what type I assign to a column, dates and times 'just work'. That's a little too magic to make me comfortable. What is really happening here, and how should it affect how I write my queries that involve date/time values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are trying to store text into a NUMERIC field, it simply stores it as text. It isn't storing a datetime value nor does it know it's storing a datetime, it's just storing the string returned by the `datetime()` function

From the documentation you linked: (emphasis mine)

> **2.0 Type Affinity**
>
> In order to maximize compatibility between SQLite and other database
>   engines, SQLite supports the concept of "type affinity" on columns.
>   The type affinity of a column is the recommended type for data stored
>   in that column. **The important idea here is that the type is
>   recommended, not required. *Any column can still store any type of
>   data.*** It is just that some columns, given the choice, will prefer
>   to use one storage class over another. The preferred storage class for
>   a column is called its "affinity".
>
> .
>
> **A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five storage classes.** When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column,
>   the storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in
>   order of preference) if such conversion is lossless and reversible.
>   For conversions between TEXT and REAL storage classes, SQLite
>   considers the conversion to be lossless and reversible if the first 15
>   significant decimal digits of the number are preserved. **If the
>   lossless conversion of TEXT to INTEGER or REAL is not possible then
>   the value is stored using the TEXT storage class.** No attempt is made
>   to convert NULL or BLOB values.

Comment: OK, this makes sense, other than it makes me ask the question, "So what exactly is the datetime() function for, couldn't I just slap the string in the column to begin with?"

Comment: Oh. Wait. Is the answer to that something like, "You don't use datetime() in an INSERT query"?

Comment: @OwenP `datetime()` is a formatting function, not a conversion function. so you'd use it when you want to convert whatever value you're passing in to a specific string representation of the date and time

Comment: Got it. Just did some more tests in the console. datetime() and the other functions always output a string, they try to interpret the input as a date/time then spit out the string in a single format. In terms of the columns, the TEXT/INTEGER/REAL stuff defines the 3 input formats that are acceptable, barring fancy use of strftime() to support some other string formats.